# ¿Como sacar el "nombre" y no la "id" en jQuery..? Desde MYSQL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli, formularios

Estoy haciendo un formulario de pedidos, utilizo jquery, en este caso, después de haber completado el formulario, he añadido un botón de "comprobar datos" en el que mando todos los datos a otro formulario con:

```
  var TratamientoOD = $('#TratamientoOD').val()
  var familiaOI = $('#familiaOI').val()
  var disenyoOI = $('#disenyoOI').val()
  var pasilloOI = $('#pasilloOI').val()
  var indiceOI = $('#indiceOI').val()
  var materialOI = $('#materialOI').val()
  var TratamientoOI = $('#TratamientoOI').val()
```

El "problema" que me surge, es que estos datos, los saco desde la base de datos, con lo que en el valor, realmente me está almacenando el ID (Cosa que es necesaria, para poder hacer los select anidados)

El caso, que cuando mando los datos según el jquery de arriba, me almacena todos los ID'S, y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de poder almacenar el "Nombre"

Es decir, que si eligen "hola" en el select, que no salga ID 1, si no que pueda verse "hola" al asignar el campo al nuevo campo.

```
  var TratamientoOD = $('#TratamientoOD').val()
```

Agradezco mucho la ayuda de todos como siempre.

Comment: Si he entendido bien, puedes usar `serialize` para recoger todos los valores del formulario. Este método te recoge los datos en la forma: `nombre=valor`, así no tienes que crear los datos uno por uno cómo estás haciendo ahora.

Comment: Estos valores que almacena serialize, se almacenaría la "id" en caso de venir desde mysql? o almacenería el texto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es el texto de la option seleccionada puedes utlizar `.text()` asi:

```js
$('#TratamientoOD').change(function() {

var TratamientoOD ="Valor vacio";
if($('#TratamientoOD').val()) {
  TratamientoOD = $('#TratamientoOD option:selected').text();
}
console.log(TratamientoOD);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="TratamientoOD">
<option value="">Seleccionar</option>
<option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
<option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
```

Comment: Estoy viendo como puedo utilizar esta opción, ya que en los campos que quedan vacíos si fuera el caso, se guarda el nombre por defecto del select, por ejemplo "seleccionar"

Comment: Por que al estar extrayendo el texto, cogería el "seleccionar" y no lo dejaría en blanco en caso de que estuviera vació :/

Comment: Puedes chequear que `.val()` no este vacio

Comment: ¿Existe algún método jQuery para esto? gracias

Comment: Se me ocurre utilizar un if(value.length>0) que lo veo una locura de código y trabajo

Comment: Otra opcion seria, si no necesitas los IDS para nada, colocar los nombres como valores.

Comment: Los IDS son necesarios, hasta que se envíe el form, casi todo el form son combinaciones de selects anidados, en algún caso de más de 10 niveles, necesito esas ids para que vayan apareciendo las características necesarias

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.  Si tendrias que chequear los valores de cada select.  O tambien podrias chequear por el valor `seleccionar` del lado del servidor.

Comment: MM, me gusta, es laboriosa tu respuesta, pero una vez hecho, ya queda hecho y se acabó! :P este es el método que voy a utilizar! muchísimas gracias! me has ahorrado un buen rato de darle vueltas al coco,  gracias!

Comment: Hey!!, Probando este código, realmente probé que no sacaba nada, pero es que no saca nunca ningún valor!!! :/

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81968/discussion-between-alanfcm-and-javier-avila-fernandez).